# Writing to file in python gives ascii error

Tags: python, utf-8, ascii

I'm trying to write results from a web scraping to a html file. I'm using Beautiful Soup to scrape links and text from  web pages. Then when I'm creating the file and writing to it, I get the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 939-940: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The line writing to file looks like this:

```
file_object.write(file_content)
```

And when I instead do this:

```
file_object.write(file_content.encode('utf-8'))
```

I don't get an error, but it can't print special characters, like å or ä.

I realize this is some kind of encoding error, but I can't understand how to get around it. The project in its entirety [is located here](https://github.com/stinaq/404finder/blob/stina/App/process_links.py), line 81, since I had trouble extracting runnable and logical sub parts.

I'm using a Mac, but had similar problem running the same script on a pc. Using python 2.7

Comment: which version of python are you using? (and uh, what is your operating system?)

Comment: Sorry, updated the question

Comment: Try using [`file_object = codecs.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html?highlight=open#codecs.open) and specifying `'utf-8'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes use open() from codecs module, or, in Python 3 normal (built-in) open() as this:

```
f = open(path, "wt", encoding="UTF-8")
```

But, if you don't want to change your code much, you do not need anything special.
The trick is to add the correct BOM (byte order mark) at the beggining of your file, so that editor that opens it knows that it is an UTF-8 file, and that should treat is as such.

```
Change you should make:
file_object.write('\xef\xbb\xbf'+file_content.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: I have now finally migrated my project to python3, and tried ```file_object = open(os.path.join(dest_dir, file_name), "wt", encoding="UTF-8")``` but I still have the strange symbols (¤) for the 'Ä' and other odd charachters. I also tried open the file in sublime explicitly with utf-8 encodning, but same result. This is quite frustrating!

Comment: This is what I have now:
```file_object = open(os.path.join(dest_dir, file_name), "wt", encoding="UTF-8")
    temp = str(file_content)
    file_object.write(temp)
    file_object.close()
``` Where file_object is html gotten from a scraping of a site

Comment: That's odd. Please add your file_content, if it is not big here, or at least part of it, - export it as: repr(file_content) so that we can try saving it as well. Try replacing str(temp) with unicode(temp) or simply skip that step.

Comment: Man, I almost went totally mental over this. Turns out the problem was much earlier in the chain. I got the html using requests, and already there the characters were broken. As soon as I added ```r = requests.get(url)
    r.encoding = 'utf-8'``` it worked. Thank you!

Comment: I am glad for you. I did never use Beautiful soup so I couldn't predicted this. That's why asked for the file example. To see when the error occured. In any case, it is best to encode/decode as soon as you can and avoid formatting, reformatting and mixing later.  So telling the Soup to do it when making request makes sense.